# Sorted set searching and ordering

Tags: python, sorting, hash, set, sortedcontainers

Python Sorted Containers package contains [SortedSet](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html), that can be initialized as follows:

```
__init__(iterable=None, key=None)
```

> key:
> Function used to extract comparison key from values.
> Sorted set compares values directly when the key function is none.

I want to store some strings that should be sorted by timestamp. If I store tuples like `("string", 1234)`, where `1234` is some monotonically increasing number like the difference between now and epoch, how can I search for the `string` in the set, and also keep it sorted using the 2nd element of the tuple? In other words, the timestamp shouldn't be used for searching, and the string shouldn't be used for ordering.

Comment: Do you want to sort a SortedSet by the second entry inside it?

Comment: @CoolCoder Yes, as my question says, find by the first element of the tuple and sort by the second. In other words, the timestamp shouldn't be used for searching, and the string shouldn't be used for ordering.

Comment: Where the documentation describes this method as `__init__(iterable=None, key=None)`, what do you suppose the `key` is for? (Hint: what does it mean when you call the standard library `sort`?)

Comment: I suspect you're going to run into a case where you need to store two data points with the same string and different timestamps, and your data structure design is going to fall apart.

Comment: @user2357112 Since the find is by key, there's never going to be two entries with the same key. A later entry would overwrite the previous one, and that's expected since the timestamps are monotonically increasing. Because a set doesn't have an overwrite function, the code needs to first delete the existing entry, and insert a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the timestamps in an auxiliary dict, rather than in the SortedSet itself. For example, something like this:

```
import sortedcontainers

class StringTimes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timestamps = {}
        self.strings = sortedcontainers.SortedSet(key=timestamps.__getitem__)

    def add(self, string, time):
        # If the element is already in the set, we need to get rid of it first, so we
        # don't corrupt the ordering when we update the timestamp.
        self.strings.discard(string)

        self.timestamps[string] = time
        self.strings.add(string)

    def remove(self, string):
        self.strings.remove(string)
        del self.timestamps[string]

    def __contains__(self, string):
        return string in self.strings

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.strings)
```

Since we're using a separate dict with string keys, we don't actually need the *set* part of SortedSet, so we could save some memory and just use a SortedList. (If new timestamps are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing, as your comment suggests, then we don't need sortedcontainers at all. We can just rely on dict ordering. I wouldn't count on that assumption holding, though - it's too likely to break once you introduce multithreading or need to sync updates across a network or something.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

s = [('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 5), ('E', 4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['key', 'ts'])
print(df)

# Output
  key  ts
0   A   3
1   B   1
2   C   2
3   D   5
4   E   4
```

Sort by timestamps:

```
>>> df.sort_values('ts')
  key  ts
1   B   1
2   C   2
0   A   3
4   E   4
3   D   5
```

New values:

```
s1 = [('C', 6), ('A', 7), ('D', 8)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=['key', 'ts'])
print(df1)

# Output
  key  ts
0   C   6
1   A   7
2   D   8
```

Merge new values:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
  key  ts
0   A   3
1   B   1
2   C   2
3   D   5
4   E   4
5   C   6
6   A   7
7   D   8
```

Remove duplicate keys:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('key', keep='last')
  key  ts
1   B   1
4   E   4
5   C   6
6   A   7
7   D   8
```